# October Surprise - (Even More) Free Points!

Tags: discussion, challenges

Any of you who have been around for awhile know I've been generous with my points in the past. Just when you thought it might never happen again, I thought I'd throw some more points your way ... *if you want them*.

Here's all you have to do. I'm going to award what are considered the top three answers on the main site with point bonuses. These points will be awarded as such: 1st - 150 points; 2nd - 100 points; 3rd - 50 points.

**Here are the rules:**

- **The "Surprise" lasts 1-31 October 2017**
- **Any answer given throughout the month is eligible**
- **Anyone can submit an answer** (even one from yourself!)

  - If someone has multiple entries, only one can win ... the next answer in line would receive the award if multiples occur
- **Links for submitted answers will be posted in this thread**

  - If answer is not posted here, it's not eligible
  - Nominate an answer by creating an answer in this thread and include a link to the nomination
  - Only one nomination per answer
  - Individuals can nominate up to three answers
  - If you nominate an answer, help it along and tell us *why* you've nominated it!
- **Judging will be based on your input**

  - Everyone on the site can vote on answers in this thread
  - Up/down votes still count
  - One extra week will be given for voting, with the final tally occurring on 7 November
  - The answer in this thread with the most upvotes wins; 2nd most gets 2nd prize; 3rd most gets 3rd prize

So you all know, I'm just doing this for fun and excitement. I'm trying to spice things up around here a little bit and thought this might be a good way to go about it. I believe it's pretty straight forward, but if you have any questions, please post them in the comments (don't use an answer), and I'll clarify whatever your concern might be. Also let me know in the comments what you think of this. If it goes over well, expect things to happen like this in the future :o)

### So on Sunday, Oct 1, please have at it and let's see some awesome answers!

**NOTE:** Mods are not eligible, so don't nominate one of my answers in here! :o)

**EDIT:** You'll note, there's new point totals I'll be given out. I had to adjust due to my stupidity ... so, more points for the winners :o) Enjoy.

Comment: Considering we are past the 7th date wise for Stack Exchange (UTM Time), I'm going to call this. It also seems we have a tie for third place. In this case, I'm going to award both Ben and tlhlngan 50 points for the contributions. So, here's the rundown: motosubatsu 1st place with 150 pts; Ceshion 2nd place with 100 points; and Ben/tlhlngan with 50 points each. I appreciate all who participated and voted!!! For those winners, congrats and well deserved!

Comment: I locked this, but could only use the "historical significance" lock (closest lock to truth). Take no heed of it.

Answer (score 6):

I will nominate [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/49040/18919) by motosubatsu.
Although the question is primarily opinion-based and many of the answers provided by other users were egregious, this user took the time to provide the OP with the detailed information the OP needs in order to make his own opinion.

Comment: Good call and couldn't agree more :o)

Answer (score 4):

I'll submit this answer, as I think it epitomizes what I'm talking about. It's a great answer!

Link: [Electric Turbine on Motorcycle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/48654/4152)

Author: [Ceshion](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/15822/ceshion)

Answer (score 3):

This is one of my signature "take the OP by the hand and walk them through a diagnosis" answers.
[Overheating Odyssey](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/48746/18919)

Answer (score 3):

I am nominating this answer https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/48197/420 by [Ben](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/14393/ben).

I am nominating that answer because he provided clear step-by-step instructions on how to root cause a really bizarre electrical issue for my car where it cranked, but did not start (remember to check comment section where a lot of valuable information resides as well).

P.S.
I have posted [second question related to the same issue](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/48913/non-zero-voltage-on-camshaft-position-sensor-power-wire-without-main-relay-is-t) where same user is helping me, but since that is still work in progress and does not have official answer yet, then I can't officially nominate anything just yet.

Comment: If there is valuable information in comments, consider incorporating that information into either the question or the answer, as appropriate. Comments are intended as ephemeral "post-it notes" which can be deleted at any time for almost any reason.